# in Gtkmm how to retrieve data from combo boxes

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtkmm

I'm currently writing an application in which I have 3 combo boxes for day/year/month, I'm wondering how to retrieve the data currently selected from the combo box and save it when a button is pressed. the problem here is simply seeing what is currently in the combo box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is method **get_active_row_number()** which returns 0-based index of selected item.

Here you can see help on that method:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.7/classGtk_1_1ComboBox.html#a53531bc041b5a460826babb8496c363b

I use it with control **ComboBoxText**.